# Squid & email traffic (25)

Tags: email, aws, smtp, squid

I'm using AWS, all traffic routed out (https) via a squid Farm in an ASG to Elastic NAT gateways. I need to route smtp port 25/110 out via this route. However new to this stuff. I believe squid is http/s and not email. If each private node is proxy configured (e.g. not transparent) to route traffic to Squid Farm. From my understanding Squid won't know what to do with this port, is it a matter of updating IPtables on the squid boxes to allow traffic through, in effect the squid node doesn't get involved, it's done just via IPtables and traffic is routed out to NAT gateways? Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Squid handles HTTP (HTTPS at a pinch, kind-of). Email is SMTP. Totally different protocols. If you're sending HTTP/S traffic via a web proxy then that also isn't necessarily following the network default route. It all depends on your configuration.

Comment: using squid as a whitelist egress proxy - not caching, website proxying etc - just gatekeeper out to tinternet

Comment: Squid isn't a gatekeeper to the Internet. It's a web proxy, so HTTP and (possibly) HTTPS only.

Comment: Tbh, with respect said Squid can be configured to do a great many things, I fear your wrong, but I completely accept it ain't an email proxy. I was just asking if this is my exit point what I should do if currently this is my only exit point. Use an email proxy? Configure iptables? Something else,??

Comment: I'm wondering if I should make an NGINX mail proxy perhaps, cause my current exit point ain't going to help me in the slightest. Initially I thought I could just add an ACL and jobs a given.

Answer (score 1):

As people have already stated, squid handles http/https connections. That may however not necessarily mean you can't proxy mail traffic that way. I've had a similar problem with blocked SMTP-traffic, so I managed to build a solution that handles the squid proxy for me, and then let postfix proceed with the SMTP relaying itself. I'm not sure if the solution works with pop as I only used this successfully with the SMTP parts. If pop is as humble as postfix has been here, is untold.

I've added the same instructions at https://www.tornevalls.se/2022/06/03/how-to-proxy-relay-smtp-over-squid-services-with-postfix-and-netcat/ but since urls tend to change over time, I'll also add the details here :)

What you need is netcat, and a script that can initiate the first part of the proxy connection. I also made sure that my smtp relay answering on port 443. By doing this, I managed to bypass the regular port 25 blocking. Since squid normally allows http/https-traffic, I made sure the SMTP relay acted like one by using those ports. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <(echo "CONNECT SMTP.SERVER.IP:443 HTTP/1.0"; echo "") -|nc squid.server.host 3128
```

This script makes sure that the proxy connection with the remote server is established, by sending the CONNECT-command with netcat. And sending an extra row to make the squid proxy to proceed with the connection. With this done, I can leave the rest of the work to postfix that takes over interactively after this.

Now I need a inetd-like service, but since I don't use inetd anymore, this is done over systemd. First, I set up the socket.

/etc/systemd/system/proxysmtp.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=ProxySMTP Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=1588
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Then, I make sure the script can be executed as a service:

/etc/systemd/system/proxysmtp@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=SMTP
Requires=proxysmtp.socket

[Service]
ExecStart=-/usr/local/sbin/smtp.sh
StandardInput=socket
DynamicUser=yes
ProtectHome=true
PrivateUsers=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then it's time to active the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable proxysmtp
systemctl start proxysmtp.socket
systemctl enable proxysmtp.socket
```

With all this done, I managed to configure postfix to connect to the local port 1588 as a relay server:

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
relayhost = 127.0.0.1:1588
```

After reloading postfix, it will now start connecting through the squid-proxy instead where it can proceed sending the e-mail.